# How can I update the first n records in a DB2 table

Tags: sql, db2

I'm having a hard time trying to update the first 100 records of a db2 table. I'm running the query from Squirrel 3.5.0

If I do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "CUSTOMERS" 
WHERE CITY = 'SAN JOSE' 
FETCH FIRST 100 ROW ONLY
```

It filters the data appropriately but when I do this:

```
UPDATE ( SELECT * FROM "CUSTOMERS" WHERE CITY = 'SAN JOSE' FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY ) 
   SET NAME = 'MARIO', LASTNAME = 'PEREZ'
```

it throws this error

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=(;<IDENTIFIER> STATISTICS, DRIVER=3.53.95
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
```

I follow the approach that is suggested in this link
http://db2guideonline.blogspot.com/2013/04/select-update-delete-n-number-of-rows.html

Would you please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Side note - tables in SQL represent un-ordered sets, so there is no "first 100 rows".  This would (if it was working) update the first 100 rows the optimizer picks (which is _probably_ the rows with the lowest primary keys in the table, but that's not guaranteed.  At all.)  Attempting to extend this for a second page of results gets more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you change your update like this.

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET    NAME = 'MARIO',
       LASTNAME = 'PEREZ'
WHERE  customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id
                       FROM   CUSTOMERS
                       WHERE  CITY = 'SAN JOSE'
                       FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY)
```

**Note**: change the `customer_id` to `identity` or `Auto generated` column of your table

Comment: ...why are you recommending changing the type of the id column?  I can't think of any reason the statement wouldn't work _regardless_ of the type of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Your update query is valid as far as I can tell (you did not say which version of db2 you are using so I assume LUW 9.7 and later). It might be the case that squirrel adds something to the query, try un-checking the checkbox that limits the number of rows that squirrel receive.

In case you have something that uniquely identifies a row (I assume cust_id here) you can use a merge statement:

```
merge into CUSTOMERS x 
using ( 
    SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
    WHERE CITY = 'SAN JOSE' 
    FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY 
) y 
    on x.cust_id = y.cust_id 
when matched then update             
    SET NAME = 'MARIO', LASTNAME = 'PEREZ';
```

Yet another option is to enumerate the rows in the table as in:

```
UPDATE ( 
    SELECT x.*, row_number() over () as rn 
    FROM CUSTOMERS x 
    WHERE CITY = 'SAN JOSE' 
)    
    SET NAME = 'MARIO', LASTNAME = 'PEREZ' 
where rn <= 100;
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` the specific rows numbered by the windowing function are random, but presumably that's not an issue, given the original query the OP was running...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative record number if your table doesn't have an id.

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS AS UPD SET SET NAME = 'MARIO', LASTNAME = 'PEREZ'
WHERE RRN(UPD)  IN 
(SELECT RRN(C)
    FROM CUSTOMERS AS C 
    WHERE CITY = 'SAN JOSE'
    FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY)
```